# django rest 400 responce when putting date field

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am putting a datetime value to my drf backend. This is my code:

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ....
    date = models.DateField(blank=true, null=true)  
    .....
```

serializers.py

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:  
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class UpdateNRetrieve(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

On my settings.py I have this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = [
    .....
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%d/%m/%Y',
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': '%d/%m/%Y',
    .....
]
```

And also this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it-IT'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Rome'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

When i make a PUT request from my front-end I am getting a 400 error (bad request) whit this value:

```
date:"04/12/1984"
```

I always get this response:

**Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: %, d, /, %, m, /, %, Y."**

I can't realize where is my error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS in settings.py should be a list :

```
'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ['%d/%m/%Y'],
```

Comment: Thank you! It must be a list of strings and not a string!

Answer (score 2):

```
'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': '%d/%m/%Y',
```

are u sure this key expects a string and not a list?

from [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#datetime_input_formats):

> A list of format strings that should be used by default for parsing inputs